# Internal Storage Increase / Replace

Tags: internal-storage, hardware

I am not convinced that My Spotify is using an entire 1GB on my new Android.

I am new to Mobile Phones, but they seem to follow the basic laws and rules of Computer Science and Telecommunication. I can not understand how 200 songs downloaded in standard quality on Spotify can use a full 1024 Mb on the phone when on my laptop the same number of songs use only 343.8 Mb. 
 I have cleared App data Caches, uninstalled Apps I am not using and my internal storage on my phone is still 7.50Gb out of 8 Gb.

I understand the internal storage package is most likely on a BGA so removing it is not an option. 
 However is it possible to put a 128GB SD in an Alcatel U5 Android Phone, and then partition the 8 Gb of Internal Storage as a system reserved, for the Android OS? Then Partition the SD as ext2 and default it to App user data.

My concern with doing this is, one I have never taken a phone apart so I do not know how the hardware is arranged, two I bought this phone 3 days ago, it still has a warranty and I don't want to void the warranty and three I do not want to have to install extra Apps to do this as I am still learning the Android OS.

I would like to know how to do this with a windows laptop, as I can get an SD Reader, and also where the SD card is inserted into the phone when ready.

Any instructions on the general procedure or specific procedure for doing this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Any chance this is a consequence of different cluster sizes between the file system on your laptop and your phone?

Comment: Where do you see that 1GB of Spotify being reported?